# Attach PDF to an Existing PDF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf-generation, itext

I want to attach a pdf file in to existing PDF file at specific location with big faceless JAVA api .Can anyone please help how can I do that ?

Comment: Which information u need? Is my answer enough?

Comment: how can i attach a page to a specific location .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the open source libary [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

This example shows how to merge two PDFs.

```
public class Merge
{
    public static final String  SOURCE_PDF      = "a.pdf";
    public static final String  APPENDED_PDF    = "b.pdf";
    public static final String  MERGED_RESULT   = "c.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, SQLException
    {
        PdfReader sourcePdf = new PdfReader(SOURCE_PDF);
        PdfReader appendedPdf = new PdfReader(APPENDED_PDF);

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(MERGED_RESULT));
        document.open();

        for (PdfReader reader : Arrays.asList(sourcePdf, appendedPdf))
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page));
            }
            copy.freeReader(reader);
            reader.close();
        }

        document.close();

    }
}
```

It is copied from [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123).

Comment: This is helpful, but could you elaborate?  Without more substance, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Hey Steve I tried this which merges fine but I need to aatach one page at suppose 7th or 9 th position in excisting pdf file How can I do that ?

Comment: See I am making a pdf from an xml using big face less report api in java. Now I want to attch a pdf at any perticular location I dont know hoe to do that :(

Comment: I don't think anyone understands what you mean by "particular location". What is the 7th or 9th position in an existing PDF file? Are 7 and 9 page numbers? If so, Christian's answer should be sufficient (I upvoted it). It's quite easy to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Yes 7th or 9th position means page numbers . For emaple if I have excisting PDF of 12 pages and if I want to attach a new PDF of 2 pages after 7th page how can I do that ?

Comment: With above solution I can attach new pdf at the end of excisting PDF